# Question about the meaning of backtick and %string

Tags: linux, bash

I am learning bash script and I am reading some sample code.
Anyone can advice me the detail and meaning of the following code? Thanks in advance!

```
END_DATE=`date -u "+%FT%TZ" `
```

Comment: The backticks are native shell syntax, the % string formatting is described in the date man page.

Comment: [What does ` (backquote/backtick) mean in commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27428/56041), [Understanding backtick (`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48392/56041), [Problem with backticks in shellscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3927062/608639), [shell - When is variable in backticks expanded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43025353/608639), [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449778/608639), etc.

Comment: One question per question, please; and demonstrate at least that you have in fact googled.

Comment: See also https://explainshell.com/ though the output it gives for this particular command isn't all that useful. Breaking it up helps.

Answer (score 0):

The backticks are performing [Command Sbustitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).  The command inside the backticks is executed in a subshell and the result is assigned to the variable.  (another syntax that would work the same in bash is `$(command)`)

The string for the date command is how format is specified for the [date command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date).